# Web Services and X509

Tags: service, x509certificate

I am getting following error in my web service when using x509 Certificate to authenticate the client.

X509Certificate2 Clnt = new X509Certificate2 (HttpContext.Current.Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate);

The error is 
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: m_safeCertContext is an invalid handle.
  at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.get_Issuer()
  at Service.HelloWorld() in c:\MyWorkSpace\SecuredWS\App_Code\Service.cs:line 40
  --- End of inner exception stack trace

Can any one put some light on it as why i am getting m_safeCertContext  as null.

Regars

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Finally, We solved this issue. If anyone interested to know i can put resolution here.

Comment: Please post your resolution to help others (such as myself) :)

Comment: Can you post your solution, please?